# htmlentities() called in JSON. Storing Arrays in MySQL DB

Tags: php, android, arrays, android-studio

I have an array of users and book ids. I have used a `foreach` loop to create entries in the database for each item in the array. **One problem though!** I have only ever used the `$stmt->bind_params` when binding strings so when I tried it with this I got this `php` error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() excepts parameter 1 to be string, array given.

My PHP Code (Get the POST param):

```
if(isset($_POST['watch'])){
$jsonwatch = $_POST['watch'];
$array = json_decode($jsonwatch, true);
foreach ($array as $item){
    $response["error"] =! ($db_watch->storeClass($array['attendees'], $array['lesson_iDs']));
}
```

My PHP Code (`storeClass()` function to Database):

```
public function storeClass($attendees, $lesson_iDs) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO watch (date, user_id, lesson_id) VALUES(NOW(), ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param($attendees, $lesson_iDs);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    if(!$result){
        echo '\n';
        printf("Error : %s.\n", $stmt->error);
        echo '\n';
        echo '\n';
    }

    $stmt->close();

    // result
    return $result;
}
```

### UPDATE!

**I forgot to mention that the array is coming from my Android Client the code for which is below. I take 2 `ArrayList`s and convert them into arrays for php:**

```
ArrayList<String> attendees = (ClassesAdapter.getAttendees());
ArrayList<Integer> lesson_iDs = (Lesson_ClassesAdapter.getLesson_IDs());

attendees.toArray();
lesson_iDs.toArray();
watch = new Watch(attendees, lesson_iDs);
```

**JSON:**

Something is calling `htmlentities()` that might be the reason but I don't know how to resolve that.

```
var_dump($jsonwatch): {&quot;73327&quot;,&quot;883992&quot;],&quot;id&quot;:0,&quot;lesson_iDs&quot;:[1],&quot;lesson_id&quot;:0}
```

Comment: `$attendees, $lesson_iDs` what are those?

Comment: sorry they're from my android client. They're the post params inside the `watch`

Comment: You either need multiple `INSERT`s or multiple `VALUES()`.  So a loop.

Comment: How would I adapt the `storeClass()` function to loop also? and would this stop my warning from happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I removed the `foreach` loop from the collection of the `POST` params:

```
// get posted params from the client
if(isset($_POST['watch'])){
      $jsonwatch = $_POST['watch'];
      $array = json_decode($jsonwatch, true);
      $response["error"] =! ($db_watch->storeClass($array['attendees'], $array['lesson_iDs']));
}
```

Then in the `storeClass` function I used post increment to cycle through both lists:

```
public function storeClass($attendees, $lesson_iDs) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO watch (date, user_id, lesson_id) VALUES(NOW(), ?, ?)");

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($attendees as $index => $attendee) {

        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $attendees[$i], $lesson_iDs[$i]);
        $i++;
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        if(!$result){
            echo 'Error: ' .$stmt->error;
        }
     }

    $stmt->close();

    // result
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the first argument to `bind_param()`, which is a string specifying the types of the parameters. It should be:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $attendees, $lesson_iDs);
```

This has nothing to do with the fact that you're looping over an array when you call the function.

Comment: I still get the warning. `Warning: mysqli::bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: You left out the first argument, a string containing letters that indicate the types of the arguments.

Comment: I now get `foreign key failed` and `Notice: Undefined offset on like 66` which is the line that says `$lesson_id = $lesson_iDs[$index];`

Comment: I thought you were passing arrays to the function.

Comment: Why do you give plural names to the arguments if they're not arrays?

Comment: They are arrays `attendees` and `lesson_iDs` are arrays with user_ids and lessons_ids

Comment: The error means that `$lesson_iDs` is a string, not an array. Can you show the `$jsonwatch` value?

Comment: The values for that are in the last update I added. `watch = new Watch(attendees, lesson_iDs)`

Comment: I can't see how that's getting into `$_POST['watch']`. Can you just post a sample of the JSON?

Comment: Sorry for my late response but I have added the JSON to the end of my question @Barmar

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON looks like `[{"attendees": [1, 2, 3], "lesson_iDs": [10, 20, 30]}, {"attendees": [5, 7, 10], "lesson_iDs": [10, 14, 20]}]`

Comment: Well I only ever use Java to convert things into JSON Objects then I use that in PHP

Comment: `var_dump($jsonwatch)` will print the JSON.

Comment: `var_dump($jsonwatch)`: `{&quot;73327&quot;,&quot;883992&quot;],&quot;id&quot;:0,&quot;lesson_iDs&quot;:[1],&quot;lesson_id&quot;:0}`

Comment: Something has called `htmlentities()` on the JSON.

Comment: Is that the cause of the issue?

Comment: It definitely could be. But that would also cause `json_decode()` to fail.

Comment: Can we move this somewhere else because its not nice to clutter the comments with a discussion?

Comment: Unfortunately you don't have enough rep to use chat.

Comment: I also need to go to sleep, it's 5am

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.execute.php) to find a good solution the first one passing the parameter in excute methodsor other to bind it.

```
<?php
/* Exécute une requête préparée en liant des variables PHP */
$calories = 150;
$couleur = 'rouge';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT nom, couleur, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND couleur = :couleur');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':couleur', $couleur, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

other way:

```
<?php
/* Exécute une requête préparée en passant un tableau de valeurs */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'rouge';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT nom, couleur, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND couleur = ?');
$sth->execute(array($calories, $couleur));
?>
```